# What does status '1' mean in SaveNetworkResp when using AmazonFreeRTOS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, freertos

My project is an app that controls a device that has the Amazon RTOS system on it. My app needs to put the device onto the local Wifi network to get it started, which involves interacting with the device through Bluetooth. Currently I am working on the Android version of the app for which I used the Free RTOS library provided by Amazon.

Upon selecting a Wifi network and providing a password, there is a Save command that I send to the device. The response corresponds to a structure called 'SaveNetworkResp' in the code, which has a simple integer status flag; zero means success.

When I run my app on a Google Pixel 5a, it works: I get a status of zero, and I can confirm that my device is actually communicating with IoT services over Wifi. But when I try it on another Android device, in this case a Samsung tablet, I get as far as picking the Wifi network and entering the password, but the status flag comes back as 1.

I can't find any documentation indicating what status '1' means in this context. The comment in the source code just says "0 for success".

Does anyone know what this status code means, or have any insight into how this could be working on one device but not the other? I confirmed using the debugger that I'm sending the exact same 'SaveNetworkReq' in both cases.

Comment: I suspect the problem is the length of the Wifi password, which is 16 characters. Perhaps the 16 characters plus the overhead of serializing the SaveNetworkReq object exceeds the MTU, which I think is 23 by default.

Comment: I tried connecting to a different Wifi network with a much shorter password, and that worked. But it's not really a solution to the problem. If MTU is the issue, why did the Pixel negotiate a larger MTU but not the Samsung?